# Function with two parameters removes all spaces from string

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

I'm learning C and I've a problem with this school homework.

I have to make function which get two strings from user as parameters. The function removes all spaces from the first string and returns the "cleaned" strings as the other parameter.

The main function ask three strings, uses function to remove spaces and prints "cleaned" strings.

My code doesn't work as it should? What goes wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeSpaces(char *, char *);

int main(){
    int i, j;
    char string[101], strings[1][101];

    for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++){

        fgets(string, 100, stdin);

        for(j = 0; string[j] != '\0'; j++){
            strings[i][j] = string[j];
        }
        strings[i][j] = '\0';
        removeSpaces(strings[i], strings[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= 0; i++){

        for(j = 0; j <= 101; j++){
            printf("%c", strings[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void removeSpaces(char *string1, char *string2){

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(string1[i] != ' '){
            string2[i] = string1[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    string2[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at `string2[i] = string1[j];`, are the indices correct? Also consider `strings[1][101];`, are `strings[1]` and `strings[2]` accessible?

Comment: What is the input you're using? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? `j` is uninitialized. in `removeSpaces` so that won't end well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be more careful when writing code. There are several things wrong:

- In `removeSpaces()`, you never initialize `j`. So it can be anything.
- You are also mixing up `i` and `j` inside `removeSpaces()`. `i` should only be used to index `string1`, and `j` only for `string2`.
- `strings[1][101]` is only one string, not 3. But the first `for`-loop in `main()` runs 3 times.
- You don't have to print strings character by character, just `printf("%s", strings[i])` or `fputs(strings[i], stdout)`.

I'm not sure why you used a two-dimensional array `strings` here. You only need two strings. Renaming the variables can also help you avoid getting confused. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void removeSpaces(const char *input, char *output) {
    int i, o;

    for(i = 0, o = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(input[i] != ' ') {
            output[o] = input[i];
            o++;
        }
    }

    output[o] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char input[100], output[100];

    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    removeSpaces(input, output);
    fputs(output, stdout);
}
```